# Show thumbnail in __str__ method in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have an `Image` model where I have typically shown the filename in the `__str__` method. I'd like to instead show a thumbnail of the image instead.

Here's my model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def filename(self):
        return basename(self.image.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your àdmin.py' instead of your `models.py`. Do the following code.

In your `models.py`

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
```

In your `admin.py`

```
from PIL import Image
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        "thumbnail", "name"
    ]
    list_display_links = [
        "thumbnail"
    ]
    readonly_fields = [
        "thumbnail", "name"
    ]
    fieldsets = [
        ("Details", {
            "fields": ("name", ("image", "thumbnail"))
        }),
    ]

    def thumbnail(self, obj):
        if obj.image:
            return mark_safe(
                '<img src="/media/{url}" width="75" height="auto" >'.format(
                    url=obj.image.url.split("/media/")[-1])
            )

    def name(self, obj):
        name = obj.image.name
        return name.replace('images/', '')
```

Below, you can see the result in your admin.

[image]

[image]